# I can't generate watershed stream order by the whitebox package in R

Tags: r, geospatial, arcgis, watershed, grass

I'm having trouble generating the drain order by the whitebox package in R. Could you help me?
When I run the wbt_strahler_stream_order function, the result is not limited to the drainage networks but is generated for the entire watershed with orders much higher than what exists.

I performed the following tests:

1. Modified the input DEM;
2. I did the procedure in ArcGIS and QGIS and it worked. However, I need to generate in R.
3. I did all the procedures in ArcGIS and QGIS. And when I got to the drainage 3. order part, I ran it in R with the wbt_strahler_stream_order function and it went wrong.
4. I installed other versions of whitebox, not all possible ones. Still, it went wrong.
5. I did the procedure with the whitebox package in Python, but it still went wrong. I'm not as knowledgeable in Python as I am in R.
6. I tried the RGRASS package and other packages in R, but I was unsuccessful.

I'll leave the data below with the script, if you could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'll leave the data below with the script, if you could help me I would be very grateful.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q8A_uYprZojXS82ysfLR7h3D0Nro9MEz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Note that Google Drive is probably a privacy nightmare for some people :( also, probably that link will be dead in few years making the question not replicable anymore. To receive more help I suggest to share the problematic snippet in the question directly